# Convert 4 Byte String Array of Hex to Decimal

Tags: labview

I am trying to convert a string of 4 bytes in a string to an integer number in LabView, currently I am using the string subset to break apart my string and then storing it into a String Indicator on the front panel, however, I need to convert that string to an int so I can show the decimal value as well as convert it from inches to mm. Here is what I'm doing now:
[image: String conversion]

I've tried converting to double using the convert string to double functions as well as I've tried splitting it up using the index array...can't quite seem to get an int out ever.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do as Ton Plomp said and use the Scan From String block.  However, in yours, you don't want to separate with commas and with spaces.  Just do:

```
%x%x%x%x
```

And that should do it for ya.  Don't forget to pull the scan down so you have 4 outputs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Scan from string](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361J-01/glang/scan_from_string/) with the following [format string](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361J-01/lvconcepts/format_specifier_syntax/):

```
%x
```

You can expand the scan from string to scan multiple items at once.

Comment: So my string is something like " 0000 0000 0000 0000".  Where the 0000 is a hex value (and yes there is a space in front of the leading zero.  I tried using the scan and using " %x, %x, %x, %x" to cut all 4 sections out and put them into numberic panels on the front and I get an error saying that the scan failed and the input string odes not contain data in the expected format.  Am I doing something incorrectly?  I can't find how to post an image on here to show what I've tried.